# Why does PyGILState_Release(…) segfault in this case?

Tags: python, multithreading, callback, segmentation-fault, portaudio

I am working on implementing asynchronous audio playback for [PyAudio](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/). The backend Portaudio implements asynchronous playback by creating its own thread and calling a C-callback function whenever it needs/has new audio data. Whenever that C-callback function is called, I am calling a previously registered Python function where the user has to supply audio data.

Since this call to Python is happening in a non-Python-created thread, [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/c-api/init.html) says I have to call `PyGILState_Ensure()` before the call to Python and `PyGILState_Release()` thereafter. It roughly looks like this:

```
int stream_callback(const void *in, void* out, unsigned long frameCount,
                    const PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo *timeInfo,
                    PaStreamCallbackFlags statusFlags, void *userData)
{
    PyGILState_STATE gstate = PyGILState_Ensure();

    /* create some python variables, as used below… */
    py_result = PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs(py_callback,
                                             py_frameCount,
                                             py_inTime,
                                             py_curTime,
                                             py_outTime,
                                             py_inputData,
                                             NULL);
    /* evaluate py_result, do some audio stuff… */

    PyGILState_Release(gstate);
    return returnVal;
}
```

Which segfaults at `PyGILState_Release(gstate)`. This callback function is invoked *very* often. Like, a few hundred to a few thousand times per second. The `gstate` is a 32 bit variable and is sometimes set to `1`, sometimes to `0` by `PyGILState_Ensure()`. It only crashes when it is set to `1`. Usually, there will be one `1` followed by two to four `0`.

This kind of feels like this `PyGILState_Release(…)` is taking a bit longer than its actual return and thus is invoked while still running or something like this.

When crashing, the stack trace looks like this:

```
#0  0x00007fff88c287b7 in pthread_mutex_lock ()
#1  0x00000001001009a6 in PyThread_release_lock ()
#2  0x00000001002efc82 in stream_callback (in=0x1014a4670, out=0x1014a4670, frameCount=4316612208, timeInfo=0x1014a4850, statusFlags=4297757032, userData=0x38) at _portaudiomodule.c:1554
#3  0x00000001004e3710 in AdaptingOutputOnlyProcess ()
#4  0x00000001004e454b in PaUtil_EndBufferProcessing ()
#5  0x00000001004e9665 in AudioIOProc ()
#6  0x00000001013485d0 in dyld_stub_strlen ()
#7  0x0000000101348194 in dyld_stub_strlen ()
#8  0x0000000101346523 in dyld_stub_strlen ()
#9  0x0000000101345870 in dyld_stub_strlen ()
#10 0x000000010134aceb in AUGenericOutputEntry ()
#11 0x00007fff88aa132d in HP_IOProc::Call ()
#12 0x00007fff88aa10ff in IOA_Device::CallIOProcs ()
#13 0x00007fff88aa0f35 in HP_IOThread::PerformIO ()
#14 0x00007fff88a9ef44 in HP_IOThread::WorkLoop ()
#15 0x00007fff88a9e817 in HP_IOThread::ThreadEntry ()
#16 0x00007fff88a9e745 in CAPThread::Entry ()
#17 0x00007fff88c5c536 in _pthread_start ()
#18 0x00007fff88c5c3e9 in thread_start ()
```

Does this make sense to anyone?

Comment: The issue you linked has to do with PyEval_ReleaseLock never being the right thing to call (it has since been deprecated), so that is unlikely to be your problem. Can you see in a debugger precisely where in PyGILState_Release the segfault is occurring? The gstate value of 1 indicates the call was from a non-Python thread, so the temporary thread state is actually being destroyed and there may be quite a bit going on.

Comment: Also, which version are you linking against? (the GIL code changed a fair bit in 3.2, so it makes a difference which version I look at)

Comment: I am working with Python 2.7.1 OSX

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the exact same issue. The fix was to call `PyEval_InitThreads()` on the main thread before any callbacks occur.

I believe the reason for this is as follows. When the Python interpreter first starts it avoids initializing the GIL because most Python programs are single-threaded and the presence of the GIL incurs some small performance penalty. So without the GIL being initialized `PyGILState_Ensure()` and `PyGILState_Release()` work on uninitialized data, causing odd crashes all over the place.

By calling `PyEval_InitThreads()` the GIL is initialized and `PyGILState_Ensure()` and `PyGILState_Release()` work correctly. If the GIL is already initialized `PyEval_InitThreads()` does nothing, so is safe to call over and over again.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into something very similar to this yesterday, though it might be worth noting that the only time I had segmentation faults was when multiple threads attempted to run `PyGILState_Ensure()` simultaneously.

In my case, it was caused by not calling `PyEval_InitThreads()` when I was initializing the interpreter (in the main thread). Note that one has to run `PyEval_ReleaseLock()` after initializing, or else you'll deadlock the next time you call `PyGILState_Ensure()`, since `PyEval_InitThreads()` implicitly acquires the GIL.

Hope this helps.